# Adding reference ID to messenger send button links

Tags: php, html, facebook

I have the following code:

```
<div class="fb-send" data-href="http://www.mywebsite.com/here/?ref=<?php $current_user->ID; ?>"  data-size="small"></div>
```

I am trying to append the current user iD to the link and have that link shared via messenger, however when the messenger share button is clicked it only shares "http://www.mywebsite.com/here/?ref="

Oh and I also have the Javascript SDK included on the page before the `<body>` tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just forgot to echo your variable :

```
<div class="fb-send" data-href="http://www.mywebsite.com/here/?ref=<?php echo $current_user->ID; ?>"  data-size="small"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div class="fb-send" data-href="http://www.mywebsite.com/here/?ref=<?=$current_user->ID?>"  data-size="small"></div>
```